# python merge two pandas data frames based on partial string match

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to Python, and I am having a lot of trouble joining two pandas data frames, because the merge should be based on a partial string match. More specifically:

I have a dataframe called `df` that looks like this:

`{ "writtenAt":"2015-01-01T18:31:01+00:00", "content":" India\u2019s banks will ramp up sales of bonds that act as capital buffers in 2015" }`

where there are about 10,000 rows that looks like above.

Now, I have another dataframe called `compNames`, which looks like this:

`{ "ticker":"A", "name":"Agilent Technologies Inc.", "keyword":"Agilent" }`

I have about 500 rows for the `compNames` dataframe.

I am trying to assign a ticker value from `compNames` to the matching entry of `df` by the following mechanism:

1. check if *any* item from the entire column `compNames['keyword']` is
   contained in an entry of `df['content']`
2. if there is a match, then return the matching word as a separate
   column of the `df` dataframe (e.g.`df['matchedName']`)
3. if there are multiple matches, then create a list of matching words
   to the corresponding entry of `df['content']`
4. Finally, join `df` and `compNames` by using `df['matchedName']` and
   `compNames['keyword']` as my key variables

What I have so far is:

```
# Load select company names
compNames = pd.read_csv("compNameList_LARA.txt")
compList = '|'.join(compNames['keyword'].tolist())
df['compMatch'] = df.content.str.contains(compList)

# drop unmatched articles
df = df[df['compMatch']==True]

# assign firm names
df['matchedName'] = df['content'].apply(lambda x: [x for x in   compNames['keyword'].tolist() if x in df['content']])
```

However, when I do this, I get an empty list for the `df['matchedName']`

Could you help me figure out what went wrong? Many many thanks!!

-Jin

Answer (score 7):

Figured it out. I just needed to do:

```
df['content'] = df['content'].str.lower().str.split()
df['matchedName'] = df['content'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item in compNames['keyword'].tolist()])
```