# Match partial strings across two data frames and merge

Tags: python, string

I have two data frames as given below. The master data:

```
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=
    [[['mayor', 'lord'], 25],
     [['prince', 'sheriff'], 33],
     [['king george', 'queen'], 32],
     [['bristol, counsellor'], 43],
     [['exchequer'], 45]],
    columns=['V1', 'V2']
)
df1.update(df1[['V1']].applymap('{}'.format))
print(df1)
```

and the other one is:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=
    [['mayor', 55],
     ['sheriff', 54],
     ['counsellor', 53],
     ['exchequer', 50]],
    columns=['Var1', 'Var2']
)
print(df2)
```

I want to map Var2 from df2 in the master data if V1 contains a corresponding Var1 value. That is my end goal dataframe is:

```
dfgoal = pd.DataFrame(
    data=
    [[['mayor', 'lord'], 25, 55],
     [['prince', 'sheriff'], 33, 54],
     [['king george', 'queen'], 32, ],
     [['bristol, counsellor'], 43, 53],
     [['exchequer'], 45, 50]],
    columns=['V1', 'V2', 'V3']
)
dfgoal.update(dfgoal[['V1']].applymap('{}'.format))
print(dfgoal)
```

I have tried quite a few things from Stack Overflow (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331390/python-merge-two-pandas-data-frames-based-on-partial-string-match)) but as the V1 is a list object and the match can be in any element in the list (like the counsellor obs), I am unsuccessful so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this solves it:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=
    [[['mayor', 'lord'], 25],
     [['prince', 'sheriff'], 33],
     [['king george', 'queen'], 32],
     [['bristol, counsellor'], 43],
     [['exchequer'], 45]],
    columns=['V1', 'V2']
)
df1.update(df1[['V1']].applymap('{}'.format))
print(df1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=
    [['mayor', 55],
     ['sheriff', 54],
     ['counsellor', 53],
     ['exchequer', 50]],
    columns=['Var1', 'Var2']
)
print(df2)


mapper = df2.set_index('Var1')['Var2'].to_dict()
def get_V3(s):
    for x in mapper:
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if x == s[i:i+len(x)]:
                return mapper[x]
        
    return None

df1['V3'] = df1['V1'].apply(get_V3)
```

I'm assuming if two or more elements appear in df2, then we use the first one, hence the return inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks very much. Unfortunately if my dataframe looks exactly like df1 (with the quotes) - this does not give the expected result.

Comment: @econbuffin2019 I thought that was a error, will try to find an answer that solves for that case

Comment: Thanks - appreciate it. Have been fiddling with this a little. nowhere yet!